# Animation is not working in java.But why?

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, repaint

What's the problem in my code while generating a simple animation, where a green ball moves from the top left corner of the window diagonally downwards. But what i am getting is ball appears at the screen after a long time and it just remains stationary.What can i do?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
class Show_starter
{

int x, y;
JFrame window = new JFrame("Graphic_show");
Graphic_panel jp = new Graphic_panel();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Show_starter start = new Show_starter();
    start.go();

}

private void go()
{

    window.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, jp);
    window.setSize(600,800);
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

class Graphic_panel extends JPanel
{

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {

        for ( int i = 0; i < 100; ++i){
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.fillOval(x, y, 40, 40);

            x++;
            y++;

            try{

                Thread.sleep(50);
            }catch (Exception e){}

            jp.repaint();

        }

    }
}
```

EDIT: i am calling repaint() also but its not working.

Comment: You will want to do some searching for similar questions in the future as this gets asked a lot, and just a simple Google search will find the problem and solution quickly. Question closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Also please look at [this question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23393664/swing-repaint-doesnt-work-in-loop-or-thread) for a similar issue, this time due to a `while (true)`.

Answer (score 2):

It should come as no surprise that nothing moves -- your `Thread.sleep(...)` is freezing the paintComponent method which will freeze all painting and in fact should completely freeze your GUI. Check similar questions on this site (it gets asked a lot), and you'll see a similar answer: use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to drive your animation.

Also:

- Don't forget to call the `super.paintComponent(g);` method in your override. This will allow the JPanel to repaint itself, covering any old pixels.
- **Never** call `repaint()` from within a painting method. This results in terrible and completely uncontrolled animation.
- Do read the [Swing Painting Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Swing Timer tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).
- Do read [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) to learn more about the details of Swing threading.

Comment: I regret I have but one up-vote to give

Comment: @MadProgrammer: it's a community wiki, so up-votes won't count, but please do improve the answer if you will.

Comment: I did realise that, but I'd still hammer the upvote button regardless, think you've covered the sentiments ;)