# Avoiding while loops in java swing

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I've read a few threads on how a while loop prevents the main thread from repainting until the while loop is done. I also saw that the way around this is to create another thread to paint. I was wondering if there is any way to avoid using a while loop all together.

So in my example, I just want to move a ball across a screen until it is at a certain point, say the middle of the screen. My current code looks something like:

```
   do {
          if (object.getPos()  < middlePt) {
             object.moveToMiddle();
             window.repaint()
           }
      while (true)
```

Where object.moveToMiddle() just increments the x axis for the object.

Comment: Possible alternatives: 1) Use a Swing Timer. 2) Use a while loop, but within a background thread. 3) Use a scheduledexecutorservice, again using background threads.

Comment: First steps in gaming huh ? It's a bit hard in the beginning. When is this triggered ? When does it start moving ? Do you have a main game loop ? The most used technique is to have a big loop that paints and moves it a little bit. `Move ball, Paint, Move ball, Paint .."

Comment: `javax.swing.Timer`, seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23393664/230513), manages just such a  thread for you.

Comment: There are no while loops in this Java Swing [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34981403/bufferedimage-not-being-cleared-before-each-rendering/35002727#35002727).

Comment: Cool thanks I'll check out the suggested links. And yes this is my first time using Java swing, trying to learn :).