# Thread.sleep stops for a second after activated and then proceeds

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  
    for(int i = 0; i<w; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<h;j++){
            for(int z = 0;z<9;z++){
                table[i][j].TurnCenterY(20);
                repaint();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Menu.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    repaint();
}
```

I am trying to spin the object 180 degrees with 20 degrees everytime for it  to look like an animation, all I'm getting is it stucks and after a few seconds it just does the rotation without any animaton

Comment: Arg, don't do that in the Swing thread :( Please see [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Comment: I was gonna mark the duplicate [Swing repaint() doesn't work in loop or thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23393664/swing-repaint-doesnt-work-in-loop-or-thread) that as a more complet answer